# I want to avoid after space through cut function in terminal

Tags: ubuntu, terminal

i have one text file named m1data.txt and the data is 0.001999|0.000000|231.000000|49.750000 in text file.
I want to cut the particular portion and get 4 diff value in four diff variable for example.

```
$d1=0.001999
$d2=0.000000
$d3=231.000000
$d4=49.750000
```

so for that i write in terminal one by one to get value f1 f2 f3 and f4

```
  cat m2data.txt | cut -d '|' -f1
    cat m2data.txt | cut -d '|' -f1
    cat m2data.txt | cut -d '|' -f1
    cat m2data.txt | cut -d '|' -f1
```

i want an output without any space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cat m2data.txt | cut -d '|' -f1 | tr -d '\n'